# How to use part of the Id or Class of DOM element with jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to use part of the **Id** or **Class** of DOM element with **jQuery** selector?

I.e. We have

```
id="Some_Extra_Name"
```

Can we use "Extra" to get all elements with jQuery?

Comment: ID attributes should be unique in order to allow you directly access to them. If you want to group a number of elements together, using a class would be preferable. With a classes, you can have more than one value so you could just add the class name for all the grouped elements.

Comment: @Lix I think you don't understand the question. Look at the answers.

Comment: @dystroy - I do understand it, and you have provided a correct answer. I still feel that selecting elements via partial ID doesn't really make sense - grouping of elements should be done with classes IMO. The selectors you have suggested that the OP use have to work much harder than if a single classname was used.

Comment: OK, I now get what you mean. Then yes, a class is both clearer and more efficient. But it's often convenient to use the ids too when it lets you make your code DRYer. Depends...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
$elements = $('[id*=Extra]');
```

If you wanted to get the elements whose id starts with `"Extra"`, you'd do

```
$elements = $('[id^=Extra]');
```

and for the elements whose id ends with `"Extra"` :

```
$elements = $('[id$=Extra]');
```

[Relevant documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `*`

```
$('[id*="Extra"]')
```